# Empty Arraystore

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have a grid referring to a store as below:

```
var s_store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
            root: 'map',
            autoLoad: True,
            ...
            idProperty:'businessResults',
            url : '....',
            fields: someRecord
            });




        var s_grid= new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel ({
        store: s_store,
        id: 's_grid',
        title:'Involvement',
        header: true,
        ....
        });

});
```

The store loads data records from database.
The problem I face is that while the database returns no rows - the store seems to show a Count of 1(the row being an empty row).
This causes the grid to also show an emtpy row.
The response from the server is as below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 07 Feb 2014 03:41:12 GMT
Content-Length: 50
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1

{"map": [
  [
    "businessResults",
    {}
  ]
]}
```

Why is this happening - and how can I prevent it?
I am using extJs 3.4

Comment: I think we may need some more code, what does the `json` look like when `map` (root node) is empty?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand correctly but I have a suggestion about this issue. There is a property in `JsonStore` which is `totalProperty`. This property tracking the returning value of the Json array. So, you can put a counter in the returning value like below :

```
// here is the count variable holding the total value of the array
$invoicesData = array("success" => true, "count" => $num, "invoices" => array());
return json_encode($invoicesData);
```

Then, in your store definition:

```
var invoiceStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
   root: 'invoices',
   totalProperty: 'count',
   successProperty: 'success',
   proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
      url: 'your-server-url',
      method: 'POST'
   }),
   fields: ['CustomerName', 'StoreName',
      {name: 'StoreNo', type: 'int'},
      {name: 'invoiceId', type: 'int'}
   ],
   idProperty: 'invoiceId'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have set "map" as root property of store and under "map", you have an empty record which would be shown in grid.

```
   {"map": [
     [
       "businessResults",
       {}
     ]
  ]}
```

It should be like:

```
    {"map": [

    ]}
```

or you should set root property of store till "businessResults" if records are under this object.

Best!!